# qml grabToImage saveToFile returns false on Android true on Desktop

Tags: android, ios, qt, qml, qtquick2

The following qml (QtQuick 2.7) code returns true on Desktop (Linux, Windows, OSX) but false on Android and ios (Android-Permissions for writing to external storage is set in Manifest.Xml).

What's wrong with the code on mobile devices? (imagePath is resolved correctly to the Standard Picture Location i.e. Storage/Emulated/0/Pictures on Android).

```
item.grabToImage(function(result) {
                    console.log(result.saveToFile(imagePath + "/picture.png"))
                });
```

Comment: The documentation says "If the grab could not be initiated, the function returns false.". So again: why is the grab not initiated on Android?

Comment: What version of Android? Setting permissions in manifest isn't enough any more, you need to go to Settings - - > Apps - - > YourApp and enable Storage permission, or you will need to request runtime permission using QAndroidJniObject.

Comment: Have you tried writing to QStandardPaths::​writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation)? You should be able to do that without Storage permission

Comment: Thank you Mark,
I will try both of your suggestions to see which one is more suitable for my app.

Answer (score 0):

[`QQuickItemGrabResult::saveToFile()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickitemgrabresult.cpp#n188) calls [`QImage::save()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/image/qimage.cpp#n3476), which unfortunately has no error reporting of any kind besides its bool return value.

If I were you, I'd change the definition of `QImage::save()` to the following, and then build qtbase:

```
bool QImage::save(const QString &fileName, const char *format, int quality) const
{
    if (isNull())
        return false;
    QImageWriter writer(fileName, format);
    const bool saved = d->doImageIO(this, &writer, quality);
    qDebug() << writer.errorString();
    return saved;
}
```

This will hopefully tell you why the image couldn't be saved.

If building Qt yourself is not an option, you could use [`QImageWriter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagewriter.html) to try to save the image directly and learn more about the error that way. You can add this to your existing main.cpp file:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

// Add this...
#include <QImage>
#include <QImageWriter>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    // ... and this
    QImage image("path/to/my/image.png");
    QImageWriter imageWriter;
    if (!imageWriter.write(image)) {
        qDebug() << "Failed to write image:" << imageWriter.errorString();
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

Once you know why the image couldn't be saved, you can remove this code.

Comment: I would try QImageWriter - but as a relative beginner I don't know how to call c++ from qml. - and how to pass the result of grabToImage to QImageWriter.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot to mention that you could do that directly from C++. I'll add an example.

Comment: Thank you very much - that works. Now I'm getting the message:
_Failed to write image: "Cannot open device for writing: Permission denied"_
I guess I have to look for the appropriate Android (and ios)-Permissions.

btw: I had to change the first 2 lines of your code:
`QImage image(100,100,QImage::Format_Mono);
        QImageWriter imageWriter(imagePath.toString() + "/test.png", "png");`

Comment: ...on ios the message reads _Failed to write image: "Cannot open device for writing: No such file or directory"_  - maybe the imagePath is wrong - my code: `QUrl imagePath;
        const QStringList picturesLocation = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::PicturesLocation);
            if (picturesLocation.isEmpty())
                imagePath = appPath.resolved(QUrl("images"));
            else
                imagePath = QString("%1").arg(picturesLocation.first());`